# Search never completes, but only with *some* terms

Tags: search, catalogsearch

Only for ***some*** terms that we have discovered (eg "backpack", etc., for other terms everything is fine) our Magento store search seems to time out after about 10s and returns a blank page saying:

"**Service Unavailable**
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
Additionally, a 503 Service Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

*What could explain such a selective and weird behavior and how could I avoid it?*

I already tried modifying the configuration parameters in System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search. I tried the 3 types of search (Like, Fulltext, Combine) and tested permitting layered navigation for any number of results, but nothing helped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging Magento, disabling extensions I found out that **the problem was caused by an extension called "Indies CallForPrice**" that was installed a long time ago, and unused. Once disabled the search started to work again for all terms.

*I cannot explain the weird behavior though (why it worked for most terms and selectively did not for others).*